# Alternative to mapply to override Error of zero-length inputs

Tags: r, dplyr, parallel-processing, tidyverse

I have inherited a bunch of code that yield an error when using mapply :
'Error in mapply(subtract_time, app_spells$AppCode, app_spells$MedianPeriod,  :
zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length'

I believe this error is inherent to mapply and I am trying to think of a way of restructing my code without running into this error.

The code has two auxiliary functions :

```
subtract_time <- function(appcode, median_pd, app){
indicator_df %>%
    filter(AppCode == appcode) %>%
    filter(date(period) == date(median_pd)) %>%
    filter(period >= median_pd) %>%
    mutate(app_use = (App == app))  %>%
    mutate(app_use = ifelse(is.na(app_use), FALSE, app_use)) %>%
    mutate(diff_period = period - median_pd) %>%
    select(app_use, diff_period) %>%
    return()
}

avg_by_app <- function(app){
  print(app)
  app_spells <- raw_usage_classes %>%
                  filter(App == app) %>%
                  select(App, AppCode, MedianPeriod)
    
  x <- mapply(subtract_time, app_spells$AppCode, app_spells$MedianPeriod, app, SIMPLIFY=F)
  overall_app_use <- do.call("rbind", x)
  row.names(overall_app_use) <- NULL
  
  avg_use <- overall_app_use %>%
               group_by(diff_period) %>%
               summarize(avg_use = mean(app_use), .groups = "drop") %>%
               mutate(app = app)
  return(avg_use)
}
```

And I am trying to run the following line that uses mapply

```
classes <- c('coding_app','design_app','video_game')
flattened <- mclapply(classes, avg_by_app)
```

But it keeps yielding the error, is there any way this mapply could be redesigned into many for loops so i can avoid the error of zero length input mixing?

thanks a lot for any help!!!!

Comment: Are you using `mapply` or `mclapply`

Comment: Are those lengths same.   i.e. in the one you are passing as input in `mclapply` `classes` is of length 1.   Also, I suspect, this could be a result of `filter` returning 0 rows

Comment: Hey Akrun, as always thanks for helping !!

Comment: Yes, i am using mclapply. Yes the filter could return 0 rows in theory, but I would like mclapply to still run even if this happens and just to override this

Comment: Consider wrapping with`tryCatch`

Comment: i.e. perhaps `avg_by_app <- function(app){
  print(app)
  tryCatch({
  app_spells <- raw_usage_classes %>%
                  filter(App == app) %>%
                  select(App, AppCode, MedianPeriod)
    
  x <- mapply(subtract_time, app_spells$AppCode, app_spells$MedianPeriod, app, SIMPLIFY=F)
  overall_app_use <- do.call("rbind", x)
  row.names(overall_app_use) <- NULL
  
  avg_use <- ...
      }, error = function(e) {
           return(NA)
     })`
 return(avg_use)
}`

Comment: It yields the same thing, I get a list returned but all outputs are : '"Error in mapply(subtract_time, app_spells$AppCode, app_spells$MedianPeriod,  : \n  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length\n"'

Comment: Is this after you tried with `tryCatch`?

Comment: You have multiple filters in different functions

Comment: Yes, after I update your with TryCatch idea for the avg_by_app ...

Comment: If you could have provided a reproducible example, it is easier to test

Comment: is there a way i can contact you? im not sure about the reproducible example